# GNU C replacement/workaround for typeof/__auto_type applied to bit fields

Tags: c, gcc, bit-fields, typeof

GNU C has two extensions that it proposes to make safe macros like `MAX` and `MIN` that will evaluate arguments only once: `typeof` and `__auto_type`.  To give examples of two `MAX` macros demonstrating each one:

```c
#define MAX(a, b) ({    \
    typeof(a) _a = (a); \
    typeof(b) _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b;  \
})

#define MAX(a, b) ({      \
    __auto_type _a = (a); \
    __auto_type _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b;    \
})
```

The problem with both of these is that `typeof` and `__auto_type` give errors if it is used on a bit field.  This example code shows the problems with a bit field using either `MAX`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Insert one of the MAX macros here

struct bitfields {
    uint8_t a: 4;
    uint8_t b: 4;
};

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    struct bitfields x = {12, 4};
    printf("%d\n", MAX(x.a, x.b));
    return 0;
}
```

GCC gives these error messages for `typeof` and `__auto_type`, respectively:

```
error: 'typeof' applied to a bit-field
error: '__auto_type' used with a bit-field initializer
```

So the question is: Why does GCC not allow these to be used with bit fields (I can't find any documentation on it), and what can be done to make a `MAX` macro that evaluates arguments only once for any type that still works with bit fields?

Comment: What should be the type of a 4-bit field?

Comment: @Barmar: gcc considers the above 4-bit bitfields to have type `unsigned int : 4`, which is different from all standard types and cannot be expressed in the language, thus cannot be used as a selector for a `_Generic` expression.

Comment: Can you use `__typeof__(+(a))` to get the promoted type according to default promotions?

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE: This works perfectly.  Never thought I'd have a reason to use the unary plus operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use `__typeof__(+(a))` to get the promoted type according to default promotions. This will work at least for bitfields of type `int`. I'm not sure how compilers treat the type for larger bitfield types, which are implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has a simple acceptable solution using the unary plus operator to force integer promotion:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ({    \
    typeof(+(a)) _a = (a); \
    typeof(+(b)) _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b;  \
})
```

Yet this approach has several issues:

- The macros use compiler specific extensions, such as `typeof` or `__auto_type`, as well as the statement expression `({ ... })` which are not portable.
- They are not really type-safe if `a` and `b` have different types: a simple expression `MAX(1L, -1U)` will even have a different value depending on the size of type `long`.
- Furthermore, the behavior will be incorrect if the expressions passed as arguments refer to variables named `_a` or `_b`.

I'm afraid typed inline functions seem a better way to portability and readability, but a more generic solution would be desirable indeed.

Comment: exactly. I do not understand this "fancy" macro love. This is one of the examples how to put a lots of effort to make the code more error prone, harder to debug and impossible to read.  +1

Comment: I'd rather not define an inline function for every single (u)int#_t type, which I use exclusively.  Also, I specified GNU C; I'm not worried about portability.

Comment: @jdk1.0: 0___________ was referring to the whole macro definition `#define MAX(a, b) ({    \
    typeof(+a) _a = (a); \
    typeof(+b) _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b;  \
})` which is non obvious to most C programmers.  Furthermore performance is no compensation for broken semantics. How would you address `MAX(1U, -1L)`?

Comment: Oh, that should not have happened.  But now SO says I can't undo it unless the answer is edited.  Is there a way to override? (Edit: I just fixed a typo, and I still can't change the vote.)